# How do I reclaim my function keys in OS X Lion?

Tags: osx-lion, function-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reset Mac Function Keys](https://superuser.com/questions/31022/reset-mac-function-keys)

I want to reclaim my function keys in OS X Lion. For instance, I want <kbd>F12</kbd> to send <kbd>F12</kbd> to my vim instance rather than increasing the volume.

How can I do this?